# Roslyn Compiler as a service

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, roslyn

I would like to ask you for explanation of how to use the roslyn as a service to integrate it in the application that I developed?

Also, how could I use it as compiler that take code form user and produce the output?

I have searched a lot but I can't understand that

I started already with a simple solution but there are some errors:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Roslyn.Scripting;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;
namespace RoslynTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();
            Session session = Session.Create();
            engine.Execute("using system;", session);
            engine.Execute("for(int i=0;i<10; i++) console.writeLine(i*1); ", session);
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are:

> Error 1   'Roslyn.Scripting.Session' does not contain a definition for 'Create'
>
> Error 2   'Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp.ScriptEngine' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp.ScriptEngine' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why do you think this should work at all? Did you use some tutorial or something? Those look just like common syntax errors during compilation. Also, make sure you are referencing all the required libraries, that's a common mistake that could cause issues like this.

Comment: Even if this compiled, you do know that C# is a case-sensitive language, right?

Comment: I am new in this programming type. Do you have any helpful tutorial please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong.

First you'll need to add the references to the appropriate compiler assemblies.

> Roslyn.Compilers.dll
>   Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.dll

Add any `using` lines you may want.

```
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;
```

Then create the engine, your session and run your code.

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine();
var session = engine.CreateSession();
session.Execute("using System;");
session.Execute("for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);");
```

Comment: Thanx Jeff for help.. however, I am new in this type of program. Do you have any tutorial.

Comment: I don't have any tutorials handy. My advice would be to just play around with it.  Browse the different namespaces and the classes available. Let intellisense guide you. The names you see is usually a very good indicator of what it does. Try to put things together and see if it works. Sure, that will take time but that's one of the best ways to learn, especially with a new technology.